# Rails polymorphic nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to create a fairly simple content management system where I have the following basic setup for my models:

```
Post
  belongs_to :post_type_fields, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_type_fields

News
  has_many :posts, as: :post_type_fields
```

(There will be other models such as documents or photos that have different fields but still need to be associated with a parent Post)

I'm trying to get my forms working so that I can have a form for a Post instance and then dynamically render the fields for the News object and then handle the creation of the Post and News together in the Post Controller.

Is this possible?  I can't figure out if it is or if I need to create a form for the News object and have that accept fields for the Post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand you correctly, but if I do, https://github.com/marcelsalathe/poly_demo might help

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think what I was trying to do is the opposite of this example.  Using the example of comments that belong to posts or editorials, i wanted to create a form for a comment that had nested fields for the post or editorial.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If the comments belong to the post, you can't do that AFAIK. The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) says that "Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent".